# Interesting issue about java and linking "&"

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I know that there isn't way to access to the links of variables in java (like in &C or &php). But for example I have such task:

```
public class JustTest {

    private int n = 1;
    private int x = 10;

    public int[] getIntegers() {
        return new int[] { n, x };
    }

    public void filledInteger() {
        int[] vals = getIntegers();

        System.out.println("Before change");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));

        vals[0] = 2;
        vals[1] = 20;

        System.out.println("After change");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));

        System.out.println("Values of name & xml");
        System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println(x);

        System.out.println("calling getIntegers");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getIntegers()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JustTest t = new JustTest();
        t.filledInteger();
    }

}
```

The result is:

```
Before change
[1, 10]
After change
[2, 20]
Values of name & xml
1
10
calling getIntegers
[1, 10]
```

So, I want to change values of "n" and "x" fields of the class instance. I can't do this by setting straightly (this->n = 20;), because I may dont know what fields do I have. Only method getIntegers knows.

(No in this code, but for example I have child class with its own fields and in the parent class I have a method filledInteger() which should change specified properties of the child class ( he knows about this properties from the method getIntegers which is abstract in the parent class and implemented in the child class))

Here is simple implementation (without inheritance), using links in php

```
<?php


class JustTest {

    private $n = 1;
    private $x = 10;

    public function getIntegers() {
        return array( &$this->n, &$this->x );
    }

    public function filledInteger() {
        $vals = $this->getIntegers();

        echo("Before change" . "<br/>");
        echo(print_r($vals, true) . "<br/>");

        $vals[0] = 2;
        $vals[1] = 20;

        echo("After change" . "<br/>");
        echo(print_r($vals, true) . "<br/>");

        echo("Values of n & x". "<br/>");
        echo $this->n , "<br/>";
        echo $this->x , "<br/>";

        echo("call getIntegers again" . "<br/>");
        echo(print_r($this->getIntegers(), true) . "<br/>");
    }

}

$t = new JustTest();
$t->filledInteger();

?>
```

The result is:

```
Before change
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 10 ) 
After change
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 20 ) 
Values of n & x
2
20
call getIntegers again
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 20 )
```

That is what I exactly need. Im just curious how do I implement this in java
Hope you understood.

Next example:

```
public abstract class ParentTest {
        abstract int[] getIntegers();

        public void fillIntegers(int[] newIntegers) {
            int[] integersOfChild = getIntegers();

            for (int i = 0; i < integersOfChild.length; i++) {
                integersOfChild[i] = newIntegers[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public class ChildTest extends ParentTest {

        private int x;
        private int y;

        @Override
        int[] getIntegers() {
            return new int[] {x, y};
        }

    }

    public class UseTest {
        void main() {
            List<ParentTest> list;

            for (ParentTest item : list) {
                item.fillIntegers(myItegers);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I need. I have a list of ParentTest instances (it may be ChildTest, or ChildTest2, or ChildTest3; but they all children of a ParentTest) and I need to fill all fields with my integer values, but I dont know if items in the list instances of a ChildTest, or ChildTest2, or ChildTest3 class

Comment: Q: How? A: You don't implement that! You could do something like that with reflection but I don't see why someone would need such thing.

Comment: Fyi: 'Linking' is actually called a reference. You're passing a variable by reference, or referencing the location of that variable. Linking is usually reserved for the idea of putting together object code when you're compiling an executable.

Comment: Q: How? A: you use the JNI (Java Native Interface) so you can use code with references and return your results to the java side

Comment: Have updated the question. @L7ColWinters it looks like solution, but its already not java(

Comment: use the instanceOf to check which child it is

Comment: Children are custom by users which use this lib... So parent dont know about every child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I implement this in Java?

With great pain via the Reflection API.  If you want to write code like this, the best idea is to use another language.

Consider programming in Groovy instead.  You can use array syntax to directly access class members by name: `t["n"] = 2;`  This works with legacy Java code, so there is no need to modify TestClass to support this usage.

Comment: yeah, reflection.. But I dont want use it

Comment: it means I need to use reflection api or dont even use java. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are talking about is called pass by reference. Java has for the most part abandoned it - it creates too many side-effects, like the one you are seeing here.

The issue is that while unfortunately you can't do this here, it actually prevents a huge number of unintentional bugs being released.

Comment: "Java has for the most part abandoned it" Java does not have pass by reference at all

Answer (score 0):

What about something like that:

```
public final class JustTest {

    private final Map<String, Object> fields;

    public void filledInteger() {
        System.out.println("Before change\n" + this.fields);

        fields.put("N", 2);
        fields.put("X", 20);

        System.out.println("After change\n" + this.fields);

        System.out.println("Values of name & xml\n" + fields.get("N")
           + "\n" + fields.get("X"));
    }

    private JustTest() {
        this.fields = Maps.newHashMap(); // guava
        fields.put("N", 1);
        fields.put("X", 10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JustTest t = new JustTest();
        t.filledInteger();
    }
}
```

Comment: Noo, I dont need collections. I want to use fields only

Answer (score 0):

Your php example does not return an array of ints, but rather an array of int pointers.  This is NOT something you can do in Java, in fact, this is NOT something you want to do in Java.  Give a use case, and there is likely a better way to solve the problem you have.

If you want to return an object that others can affect and that are contained as member variables, do that.  An ArrayList, HashMap, etc... there are plenty of things that can fit your needs.  If you are given someone elses class and you must stick your nose in their code, you can get around their private declaration doing the following:

```
public void setN(JustTest j, int n) {
    //You would handle some exceptions here also
    Field f = JustTest.class.getDeclaredField("n");
    f.setInt(j, n);
}
```

Comment: This requires rewriting the TestClass.  It does not solve the problem of performing the same action on multiple members of an existing unmodifiable class without code duplication.

Comment: I need use of fields. Not arrays or collections instead.

Comment: updated with the only way to do it with a field that is a primitive that is copied into a new array.  Ideally you would just expose setters on the JustTest object, use a wrapper class around the int, or store the data in a collection that is referenced

Answer (score 0):

You can't do individual fields without reflection, but you can change the contents of collections.  Note that this is not really intended behavior, but rather something you have to be careful of when using collections.

This outputs 5 3 2 4 2 4

```
public class Test
{
  public Vector<Integer> args = new Vector<Integer>();

  public void fillArgs()
  {
    args.add(5);
    args.add(3);
  }
  public Vector<Integer> getArgs()
  {
    return args;
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Test s = new Test();

    s.fillArgs();
    Vector<Integer> temp = s.getArgs();
    for (Integer i : temp)
      System.out.println(i);
    temp.setElementAt(2, 0);
    temp.setElementAt(4, 1);
    for (Integer i : temp)
      System.out.println(i);
    for (Integer i : s.getArgs())
      System.out.println(i);
  }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use fields, and dont use collections